# OpenLayers with ArcGIS REST API identify layer feature

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server

We are using ArcGIS REST services on OpenLayers. The layers are placed on the map correctly but how to identify a layer feature on mouseover or mouse click and get the details of the particular layer feature?

Is there any function in OpenLayers library to do it..?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inbuilt in OpenLayers that can directly call the Identify Task on the ArcGIS Server's REST Endpoint.

If you are fairly comfortable with JavaScript, then there is some hope. You can refer to the AgsIdentifyTask.js code present in this sandbox: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/august/trunk/lib/OpenLayers/Control/

There is a sample [here](http://www.mkgeomatics.com/apps/REST_Dev/agsIdentifyTask.html), but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta, I checked the sample but its not working. I selected a layer and click on identify button(to activate control) and click(CTRL+click(as they mentioned)) on the layer. But nothing happened.. :(

Comment: @MufeedKKasim I just linked to the sample, so that you can have a look at the source code. Have you added the source code of the control to your application?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still looking for an Identify click event on ArcRest93 layers in OpenLayers 2.x, I have used [the following](https://github.com/point97/marine-planner/blob/master/media/assets/openlayers/arcgisrestidentify.js) to [successfully handle click events for ArcRest93 layers](https://github.com/point97/marine-planner/blob/master/media/js/map.js#L397).

I originally found the code in an [OSDir thread](http://osdir.com/ml/openlayers-development-gis/2010-12/msg00035.html) by someone named giovanni (maybe Giovanni Allegri?).

Which itself refers to the code found in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1GyFaAJi).